# Can I create synchronous function in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have already saved some data to Storage in Ionic 2.

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
... ... ...

constructer(public storage: Storage){}

this.storage.set('usertype', usertype);
```

Now I have to create to get data from storage.
And the program logic must be to execute next functions after get data using created function in storage.
How can I create Get function or build program logic?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like if you're using Ionic2's nativeStorage module it returns a promise on resolution, so using your example you can do do something like...

```
import { NativeStorage } from 'ionic-native';
... ... ...

NativeStorage.setItem('usertype', usertype);

.... 

NativeStorage.getItem('usertype')
  .then(
    // everything here happens once you actually have the data
    data => console.log(data),
    error => console.error(error)
  );
```